# Как сгрупировать по ID все значения в лист?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, обработка-данных

Есть фрейм данных со столбцами `id` и `value`. Для одного `id` есть несколько полей с разными значениями.

Как пройтись циклом `for`, чтобы переместить все значения в одну строку через запятую?

Входные данные:

```
id value 
-- -----
0  7984 
0  488 
0  333 
0  499 
1  22 
1  445
```

Ожидаемые данные:

```
id value 
-- -----
0  [7984, 488, 333, 499]
1  [22, 445]
```

Comment: id    value 
0 7984
0 488
0 333
0 499
1 22
1 445

Comment: Уже исправил сам

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Группируем по одному столбцу, а значения другого преобразовываем в списки:

```
res = df.groupby("id")["value"].apply(list).reset_index()
```

результат:

```
In [25]: res
Out[25]:
   id                  value
0   0  [7984, 488, 333, 499]
1   1              [22, 445]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dict_ = {}

for id, value in zip(data["id"], data["value"]):
    try:
        dict_[id].append(value)
    except:
        dict_[id] = [value]

res = pd.DataFrame([{"id": list(dict_.keys()), "value": list(dict_.values())}]).T
```

Comment: ну если так, то `res =  pd.DataFrame([dict_]).T` )

Comment: @MaxU просто в pandas не разбираюсь

Comment: В идеале нужно получить такой словарь: `dict_ = {"id": [0, 1], "value": [[7984, 488, 333, 499], [22, 445]]}`, тогда можно будет сделать `res = pd.DataFrame`, чтобы получить фрейм как у меня в ответе

Comment: а можно фрейм получить, а не лист?

Comment: @MaxU все готово